# MongoDB network subnet CIDR filter

Tags: mongodb

There is a **`tag`** collection which contains ip cidr / tag.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "tag" : "office",
    "ip" : [ 
        "172.200.0.0/16", 
        "172.201.0.0/16", 
        "172.202.0.0/16", 
        "172.203.128.0/17", 
        "172.240.0.0/16", 
        "10.99.0.0/16"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "tag" : "server",
    "ip" : [ 
        "10.83.0.0/16", 
        "10.84.0.0/16"
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to search the **`tag`** of ip **`172.202.1.5`** ? ex:

```
> db.getCollection("tag").find({ --how-to-filter-ip-tag-- }, {tag: 1})
```

Comment: The basic wisdom there is to save the IP address as a "number" and not a "string". As a numeric value you can basically apply the math for the sort of sub-net queries you want.

Comment: Could we do it like this ? - < Create an IPv4/IPv6 CIDR matcher > -
 https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29166?jql=text%20~%20%22cidr%22

Comment: [Read the duplicate question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591234/save-ip-address-in-mongodb). That's why your question was linked to it.

Comment: And you are linking to an "internal server issue". It's not a language feature for queries.